# Split comma separated list on separate line (notepad++ / regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a few files where each file has some text which has a description and list of tags.

I would like to manipulate the tags in the text with notepad++ and regular expressions in each file.

I could easily replace the commas with /r/n, but that would also take into account the description part where there are also commas and I want to keep that intact. I only need to manipulate the tag part.

Plus, there is not always the same amount of tags (sometimes there are 4, sometimes more, it varies).

Original input text:

```
Description: blah, blah, blah, slsls,

tag: 
 - hello, bye, Thanks, etc, Notepad
```

Desired output text:

```
Description: blah, blah, blah, slsls,

tag: 
     - hello
     - bye
     - thanks
     - etc
     - notepad
```

Any idea how I could achieve this? thanks much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^tag:\s+|\G)[,-]\h*(\w+)`
- Replace with: `$1\t- $2\n`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # start group 1
    ^           # beginning of line
    tag:        # literally
    \s+         # 1 or more spaces
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)               # end group
[,-]            # comma or hyphen
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(\w+)           # group 2, 1 or more word character (you can use [^\s,])
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
\t          # a tabulation
-           # a hyphen followed by a space
$2          # content of group 2
\n          # linefeed
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much. I just replaced (\w+) with ([\w ]+) to account for multi word tags example. Tag: blah, multi word, singleword